# Are sibling aggregation computed concurrently in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, concurrency, elasticsearch-aggregation

Elasticsearch is such a nice database. One of its awesome features is that you can execute more than one aggregation in on the same set of data, i.e., on the same *context*.

For example, you can have a request like the following.

```
POST /some_index/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            // Some query that defines the context
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "agg1": {
            // Some aggregation on the above context
        },
        "agg2": {
            // Some other aggregation on the above context
        }
    }
}
```

Nice! However, it is not clear if the results of `agg1` and `agg2` are calculated **concurrently** by Elasticsearch engine or one after the other.

Stating that the data are extracted using the `query` statement only once, is there anyone that can answer this question?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding since [Sibling](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html) aggregations are:

> Pipeline aggregations that are provided with the output of a sibling aggregation and are able to compute a new aggregation which will be at the same level as the sibling aggregation.

They are computed one after the other